# Idiorm and Paris association with custom foreign key

Tags: php, orm, idiorm

i've tested Idiorm and Paris library and i found a strange behaviour when i use association with custom foreign_key
This is the code

Class User extends Model{

```
public static $_table = 'User';
public static $_id_column = 'UserId';

/*
 * Associations
 */
 public function department() {
    return $this->has_one('Department','DepartmentId');
}
```

}
Class Department extends Model{

```
public static $_table = 'Department';
public static $_id_column = 'DepartmentID';

/*
 * Association
 */
public function user() {
    return $this->belongs_to('User','UserID');
}
```

}
Custom foreign key is mandatory because the database schema doesn't modifiable.
the result on query log test:
       $department= Model::factory('Department')->find_one(23);
       $user = $department->user()->find_many();
is:
SELECT * FROM `User` WHERE `UserId` = '' LIMIT 1
why?

**strong text**
sorry,
my mistake in order of relation
i configure in a wrong way has_one and belongs_to
the correct code invert the relation

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: the query in related table is not correct. don't use the correct foreign key